# Let users sign in with eIDs - do I need government authorisation? (scope: all nation-states)

Tags: cryptography, certificate-authority, identification, bitcoin, international

I've decided to launch a crypto-basic income system.

Crypto UBIs are [pretty popular](http://motherboard.vice.com/read/how-bitcoin-could-make-distributing-a-universal-basic-income-actually-possible) now.

For me, it seems like an open nation-state ID should exist by now (2015). However, Mike Hearn, Bitcoin core-developer and a long time software engineer, outlines in his [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coj3uBrnxIg&feature=youtu.be&t=11m20s)  that NFC chips on nation-state passports could be hacked to provide IDs for crypto-developers. However, shouldn't eIDs be able to do that? Is it possible to let users sign in with their eIDs, or do applications need some type of certification that's really hard to get for crypto apps?

I know decentralized IDs are on the frontier ([discussion](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/366/discussion-decentralized-id)), but eIDs have been around for at least a decade and I should be able to use those. What IDs are available for me on the (global/local) market **right now**?

Comment: Whether you need government authorization is more of a legal question than an infosec one.

Comment: Germany has an eID function on their ID cards but nobody uses it. A) most people think it's too large of an risk to lose control B) you'd have to buy a card reader C) there only like 20 applications over whole Germany with most not affecting you D) providers need to have special certification and special stuff and such holding many back (I think). I think these points aren't restricted to Germany. However you may take a look at Estonia. They actually have client-certs on their cards... There's a paper on eprint about that one... https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/538.pdf

Comment: One list of ID' systems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number

Comment: @NeilSmithline I don't see how your comment adds to my question. The reason you have cryptographic ID systems (eID, Mike Hearn's idea of hacking crypto-signatures on passports, future decentralized IDs on something like Ethereum) is because it's extremely easy to sign up to a service using someone else's national identification number. That's why cryptographic ID systems are [in the number of quindecillions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZloHVKk7DHk), instead of old ID systems that were less secure with around a 1,000,000,000,000 possible keys.

Comment: You ask about electronic ID systems and that wiki page lists several. Perhaps I misunderstood your question.